# Syft : what's the difference between scanning images and scanning docker's overlayFS storage directories?

Tags: docker, github, package, docker-image

This question is about the [Syft tool by Anchore](https://github.com/anchore/syft) :

I want to know what's the difference , when scanning images, between using the `syft packages docker:[img]:[tag]` command and using `syft packages dir:[directory]` command on all of the image's storage directories. Will the results be different?

---

Syft offers a very simple interface for scanning Docker images: syft packages `docker:[img]:[tag]`.

But images, by default, are stored using Docker's overlayFS storage driver, in several directories in the path **/var/lib/docker/overlay2/**. I was wondering, in the case that the images are, in fact, stored in this way, what will be the difference between scanning the image using Syft's image scanning interface and scanning it by scanning these directories?
Will I see packages in one scanning that I won't see in the other?
I performed some checks on my machine, but:

1. the results were ambiguous.
2. I don't know if the results are specific to my machine+images+configs or is there a general answer.

so...

- If the results of scanning an image and scanning its storage directories are not the same: what's the difference?
- If they ARE the same: why does Syft focus on developing a specific search dedicated to images ( i.e. `syft packages docker:[img]:[tag]` ) and why does it create files in /tmp (see below:)?

---

My guess was the results should be the same and I assumed `syft packages docker:[img]:[tag]` will use the directories in **/var/lib/docker/overlay2/** and read from them, but after using `strace` and `lsof` I saw that it doesn't. It only creates some versions/copies of them inside **/tmp/stereoscope-cache[number]** and I don't understand how, if it does not read from the **/var/lib/docker/overlay2/** directories. what are these files in /tmp and how does it create them without opening files in **/var/lib/docker/overlay2/**?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> If the results of scanning an image and scanning its storage directories are not the same: what's the difference?

Short answer:

- For images: syft reports packages that are installed (such as RPMs in the RPM DB)
- For directories: syft reports packages that are installed or declared (such as packages found in a python requirements.txt file)

Syft has a collection of "catalogers" that do all of the heavy lifting of finding packages. There is typically one or more catalogers for a single packaging ecosystem. The set of catalogers used depends on what is being scanned.

Why do this?

It may be that you have a setup.py or a requirements.txt baked into a docker image, however, the packages declared in these sources may or may not have actually been installed in the container image. A more accurate way to figure if a python package has been installed is to check for egg or wheel metadata files within a site-packages directory, which is what syft does when looking for "installed" python packages.

However, when scanning a source repository you tend to not have any packages installed in the source repo but a manifest file (such as a python requirements.txt) describes what will be installed or dependencies of the application.

Code that distinguishes which cataloger to use based on what is being scanned, an image or a directory: https://github.com/anchore/syft/blob/v0.46.3/syft/pkg/cataloger/cataloger.go#L37-L70

> My guess was the results should be the same and I assumed syft packages docker:[img]:[tag] will use the directories in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ and read from them, but after using strace and lsof I saw that it doesn't.

Correct! The overlay2 directories are not leveraged directly.

In an attempt to stay as cross platform as possible syft uses the docker API to get all information about container images (reading from the overlay2 directories directly would require more of a lift depending on which OS you're on). First thing syft does (or really the underlying lib [stereoscope](https://github.com/anchore/stereoscope)) is to [obtain a `tar` of the image](https://github.com/anchore/stereoscope/blob/main/pkg/image/docker/daemon_provider.go#L274) in the same way that `docker image save` does. Stereoscope parses the response and provides an API for syft to query and access the underlying files in the image.

(*Disclaimer: I'm a developer on syft and stereoscope.* )